# nested if statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need an if-statement that creates a field called "part_ID".  This field  takes the field "p.ID" and looks it up in "a.Part_ID".  If the part_ID is not null in "a.Part_ID", then  the part ID should remain unchanged and just be "a.Part_ID".  If the part ID is null, then it should lookup the part ID in "b.Part_ID_Not_cataloged" and if the part ID is listed, then it should substitute it with "b.related_Part_ID_in_catalog".

```
   SELECT a.Part_ID, p.ID, b.Part_ID_Not_cataloged, b.related_Part_ID_in_catalog
     FROM (SYSADM_PART AS p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_concatenated_data_view_only AS a ON p.ID = a.Part_ID) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Part_ID_Not_in_catalog_entry AS b ON p.ID = b.Part_ID_Not_cataloged;
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: Hi, I would post the code if I knew SQL, but unfortunately I dont, hence why I am posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)